# Android C2DM Device Registration giving a 401 error

Tags: android, push-notification, android-c2dm

I am attempting to register an Android device with Google's C2DM service, but I am getting the following in logcat when I attempt to do so upon install of the app on the phone:

W/DefaultRequestDirector( 1210): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {}
D/C2DMRegistrar( 1210): [C2DMRegistrar.30] register: http error 401
E/C2DMRegistrar( 1210): [C2DMReg] handleRequest caught org.apache.http.auth.AuthenticationException

I'm also printing what I'm sending out to Google to logcat. It follows explicitly with only the email address taken out. This email address is the one I registered with Google to be the sender of the push notifications.

Intent extras: Bundle[{sender=me@myemail.com, app=PendingIntent{4471c300: android.os.BinderProxy@44762840}}]

ComponentName object (result of startService call): ComponentInfo{com.google.android.gsf/com.google.android.gsf.gtalkservice.PushMessagingRegistrar}

To clarify, this is NOT a problem with sending an actual message to a device - I have not got that far. This problem is with getting a device registered.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you need to make sure you've done to get through the registration:
1. Signup on the Android C2DM website with a google email account
2. use that account to send the registration intent to the google server. 
Your registration intent should look something like this:

```
public void registerApp() {
    Intent intent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTER");
    intent.putExtra("app",
            PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
    intent.putExtra("sender", "youraccont@gmail.com");
    ComponentName result = startService(intent);
    Log.d("Intent", "" + result);
}
```

Also be sure to declare this in your manifest

if the email account your using is not managed by google that could also be causing the issue. You can just sign up for a new gmail account to use for your c2dm push notifications.

hope this helps